# Limiting variable scope without nesting into a subclass or mixin?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I would like to use a variable in a couple of classes, so i do:

```
$height: 100px

#foo
  height: $height

#bar
  height: $height
```

But this pollutes the global variable scope, so i would like to use a subscope.

When i have a common container for the elements, it's simple:

```
#common-container
  $height: 100px

  #foo
    height: $height

  #bar
    height: $height
```

But instead of polluting to global variable scope, this approach pollutes to resulting CSS: chained selectors are absolutely unnecessary. In some cases there's just no common container for the elements, so this approach is not an option at all.

I tried working around this issue by using a dummy mixin:

```
=local-scope
  @content
```

It seems to work fine:

```
+local-scope
  $foo: foo

@warn $foo // -> Error: Undefined variable: "$font-size".
```

But if a variable is declared before using the mixin, it gets overwritten! :(

```
$foo: foo

+local-scope
  $foo: bar

@warn $foo // -> bar
```

The question is: how do i limit a variable scope correctly without messing with the global namespace and without unnecessarily chaining selectors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While this prevents inline `@imports`, I think that's a dark pattern anyway, as it secretly encourages complex specificity.

```
@at-root {
  $this: that;  // not a global variable

  .your-original-css {
    // rules
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@if` statements for this purpose:

```
@if (true) {
    $foo: bar;
    @debug $foo;
}

@debug $foo; // undefined
```

Just be aware that you can't import within if statements.

Comment: The `@if` technique pollutes the global scope as well: http://sassbin.com/gist/7016366/

Comment: Well sure, but that happens with mixins, too.  Ideally, your truly global variables wouldn't be named something you'd be likely to reuse elsewhere.

Comment: If i'm forced into using unique names for local variables, there's no sense in using the `@if (true)` trick in the first place. :(

Comment: What would a global `$height` variable be for, though?  I name all of my global variables as specific as possible (`$logo-width`, `$icon-width`, etc.), and then use terse names for variables I don't care get overwritten or destroyed (`$w`, `$h`, etc.).

Comment: You're right, cimmanon. I was just looking for a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

So this is not available in Sass.

There's a ticket for that in the Sass issue queue: https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/136

But it's not going to be implemented until Sass 4.0.